# how to load iframe using contentscript and override xframe

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

First of all, is there another built in way to do this like webview is in phonegap, so I can load an external site into a div or div like element. I know webview exists for chrome apps, but i couldn't find anything for extensions.

Basically i want to show preview of pages on links..

To do that I am trying to load urls of links using by setting src of iframes using content script. However, for most urls,  I get an error that xframe not allowed.

what are my options.

Comment: You can render html content manually into a div if you want, but it might get problematic if you are actually talking about full pages.  Are you trying to do this for all pages, or just a few you host?

Comment: For result page only but links can be anything, i tried loading in div by setting its html. Hell broke lose. First like 29 js errors and then all css got messed up to.

Comment: extensions like these seem to be doing it just fine, and i dont know how.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-preview/ohmamcbkcmfalompaelgoepcnbnpiioe/related?hl=en

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-previews/hlbhbhdjmllabhmeoehogilodnpbmhgj?hl=en

Comment: Actually the comments show it doesn't work anymore: "AS of Chrome Version 30.0.1599.69 m Google has disabled loading HTTP content into the preview when you are on a secure (HTTPS) page e.g. twitter, google, facebook, etc. (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238484) This prevents ezLinkPreview from working on those pages with any external links."

Comment: is there a way to show like popup that stays on the page. Or make iframe separate so mixed content doesnt matter

Comment: ok i got it working, i had to go through so many obstacles.

First CrossOrigin, then Xframe disabled header, then Mixed Content Https/http. Each time i thought this was it.

Comment: First i added permissions to get other domain's content, then i added background page for removing xframe headers, then after lots of googling i miracously found that you could use sandbox to overcome mixed content error, then it turns out most sites were replacing top frame by redirecting it, which sandbox attribute of iframe also solved by not allowing scripts to run. So more or less i can now show a site from different domain, over different protocol, inside iframe ..given its js is turned of.

Answer (score 0):

xframe is pretty full proof, however, if you aren't referring to specifically an iframe, you could always use a web-proxy such as node-unblocker for node.js, or miniProxy for PHP.